# Create Order programatically, not working via cron

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, crontab

I am working on to create order programatically using cron. If run this cron using [n98-magerun2.phar](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2) plugin its works fine.

```
 sudo -u www-data ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run  "cron_name"
```

But, while system cron job run this cron, Its **stop while set shipping method**.

**What I Did:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class DailyOrder extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $customerSession;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_productFactory;

    protected $quoteManagement;

    protected $customerFactory;

    protected $customerRepository;

    protected $orderService;

    protected $cartRepositoryInterface;

    protected $cartManagementInterface;

    protected $shippingRate;

    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function CronDailyOrder($one_time_order, $order_price)
    {
        //init the store id and website id @todo pass from array
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

        //init the customer
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create()->load($one_time_order["customer_id"]);
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer_login = $this->customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

        if ($customer_login->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_logger->addDebug("Customer Logged in");

            /* order place based on subscription */

            //init the quote
            $cart_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
            $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart_id);

            $cart->setStore($store);

            // if you have already buyer id then you can load customer directly
            $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
            $cart->setCurrency();
            $cart->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

            /*start to add product to cart */
            try {
                $product_id  = $one_time_order['product_id'];
                $price  = $one_time_order['product_price'];
                $quantity  = $one_time_order['qunatity'];
                $this->_logger->addDebug("cart Product id: " .$product_id);
                $this->_logger->addDebug("cart Price: " .$price);
                $this->_logger->addDebug("cart quantity: " .$quantity);
                $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
                // $product->setPrice($price);
                $product->setPrice($order_price);
                $cart->addProduct(
                                $product,
                                intval(1)
                            );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_logger->addDebug("addtocart exception " .$product_id);
                $result['Status']= "500";
                $result['Message']= "product_not_addtocart";
                return $result;
            }
            //Set Address to quote

            /*Prepare address for billing and shipping address*/
            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $this->_logger->addDebug("get customer info");
            $users_data = $this->customerRepository->getById($one_time_order["customer_id"]);
            $customer_data = $users_data->__toArray();
            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $address = array();

            $address['firstname'] = "xxxx";
            $address['lastname'] = "xxxxx";
            $address['street'] = "xxxxx";
            $address['city'] =  "xxxx";
            $address['country_id'] = "xx";
            $address['region_id'] = "xxxx";
            $address['postcode'] = "xxxxxxx";
            $address['telephone'] = "xxxxxx";
            // $address['save_in_address_book'] = "1";
            $this->_logger->addDebug("assign shipping address" . serialize($address));

            $shipping_addr = array();
            $shipping_addr['addresses'] = $address;
            // print_r($shipping_addr['addresses']);
            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            //Set Address to quote @todo add section in order data for seperate billing and handle it
            $cart->getBillingAddress()->addData($shipping_addr['addresses']);
            $cart->getShippingAddress()->addData($shipping_addr['addresses']);

            $this->_logger->addDebug("set billing and shipping address");


            // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
            $this->shippingRate
            ->setCode('freeshipping_freeshipping')
            ->getPrice("0");

            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $this->_logger->addDebug("currently we are set free shipping");
            $this->_logger->addDebug("before get shipping address");

            $shippingAddress = $cart->getShippingAddress();

            $this->_logger->addDebug("before get shipping address");

            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            // set in order data

            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method

            $this->_logger->addDebug("set shipping method");
            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $cart->getShippingAddress()->addShippingRate($this->shippingRate);

            $this->_logger->addDebug("free shipping");

            $cart->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method

            $this->_logger->addDebug("assign payment method");

            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            //@todo insert a variable to affect the invetory
            $cart->setInventoryProcessed(false);

            $this->_logger->addDebug("invetory process");

            // Set sales order payment
            $cart->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

            // Collect total and saeve
            $cart->collectTotals();

            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $this->_logger->addDebug("collection total");

            // Submit the quote and create the order
            $cart->save();
            $this->_logger->addDebug("save the cart");

            $this->_logger->addDebug(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            // total_qty_ordered

            $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
            $order_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());
            if ($order_id !="") {

               echo "order placed successfully";

            } else {
                $result['Status']= "500";
                $result['Message']= "order_not_placed";
            }
            return $result;
        } else {
            $this->_logger->addDebug("Customer not Logged in while cron");
            $result['Status']= "500";
            $result['Message']= "customer_not_login";
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Once Run My custom cron, Its will call this Helper class and place order.

While running this cron, stop before below line.

```
  $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
```

Suggest Me, Why it's failing in this line,

**Note:** Same cron I try to run using `n98-magerun2.phar` it works fine.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this, running into similar issue